# Filepath when loading ColorMap in Directx 11

Tags: c++, directx, filepath

Greeetings everyone :)

I expect the following question to be pretty easy to answer. I am currently toying around with Directx 11 and building a game. Currently all 2D files are stored in the same visual studio folder as my source code but i want to split it into several subfolders, like sprites/cmdButton.png and models/tower.obj. I use the following code:

HRESULT d3dResult;

```
// Load Sprite Image
    d3dResult = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(d3dDevice,
        filename_, 0, 0, &colorMap_, 0);

if (FAILED(d3dResult)) {
DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to load the texture image!");
}
```

Where filename is "CmdButton.png" etc. I've tried to put it in a folder Sprite and write "Sprite\CmdButton.png" but it does not seem to work. Does anyone know how the syntax is if you want directx to locate the file in a subfolder?

best regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to be aware of:

1. When you run your project from the Visual Studio IDE (if that's what you're using), the default working folder is the one containing your project file. However, when you run the executable directly, the working folder will be the folder containing the exe. So if you are using a relative path to a sub-folder, it will be different in each case.
2. If you want to specify a path name, you *must* escape the backslash character. So use something like `"Sprite\\CmdButton.png"` instead of `"Sprite\CmdButton.png"`.

Comment: Now it gets tricky, i did as u said and wrote "gui\\background.png"
then i created a folder in the source folder called gui and moved background.png to this folder, then it crashed. I copied background.png to the source folder so it was two places then it worked. Now visual studio wants it both places for the filepath to work... jesus

Comment: Having both files i investigated which one it rendered and it proved that is takes the one located in the locale folder, "gui\\background.png". For some reason unknown to me it still wants the file to be located in the source folder as well... really giving me a headache

Comment: Your suggestion lead me on the right path :) thx a lot. Everything works now.